# How to pass large cable bundle through drywall?

Tags: wiring, data-wiring

I’m moving all my network equipment to a central location inside a closet. I will mount the switch on the wall, and have about 14 Cat6 cables passing through the interior wall and going in different directions.  What's the best way to do this?  I have seen passthrough wall plates like this, but I don't like that they allow airflow and a potential entry for mice or other critters.
[image]

I have also seen recessed boxes like this with a punchdown patch bay, but this doesn't actually get the wires into the closet.
[image]

For smaller installations like in each room, I would use keystone plates like this.  So I could mount four of these right next to each other.  Is that the best approach?

[image]

Comment: Two basic grommets with PVC between is the usual approach. There are some pre-made. Think hotel door peephole.

Comment: Do you have a photo? I’m not sure how this would make a seal to keep hot attic air out

Comment: I'm not sure how that would get past your wall plates in the first place, but [here you go](https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Pass-Through-Wall-Port/dp/B07MVND474).

Comment: Oh I see. That looks good for going from one room to another, but I need to go from a conditioned room to unconditioned space

Comment: Look for pass through devices to allow a cable to come through, but are small enough to block rodents and act as a firestop, which I feel is an important feature.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a putty called "duct seal compound" which you can pack into the opening of a pass-through plate to seal the opening. I couldn't say whether it is rodent-resistant (few things are) but it may get the job done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Keystone jacks come up to 6 ports on a single-gang plate (you show 4s) so three of those would do the job. You can also get a 12-port model for a double-gang box (or boxless low-voltage trim ring, which simplifies the wire-handling behind the plate.)

6 port surface-mount boxes are also common.